# 2 Squares and their ratios.

Tags: geometry

I just found this out.

The ratio of the areas of the squares, and the ratio of their perimeter. It looks like they're connected in some way.

As an example:
if you have a square 20X20 and another one with 100X100
The the ratio of the areas is 1:25, and the ratio of the perimeters is 1:5.
These are the same if you multiply ratio of perimeter with 5.

Another example:
12.75X12.75 and a 50.35X50.35.
The ratio of the areas is about: 162.5625:2535.1225
The ratio of the perimeters is about: 51:201.4
These can be made to these | 1:15.5947 | 1:3.9490 |

These are also the same if you multiply ratio of perimeter with 4, if you had the rest of the decimal numbers.

Does this apply with all ratios or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Consider two squares, one with side length $S$ and the other with sidelength $s$.  Their areas will be $S^2$ and $s^2$ respectively.  Their perimeters will be $4S$ and $4s$ respectively.  The ratios can be simplified to $1:\frac{s^2}{S^2}$ and $1:\frac{s}{S}$ respectively.  Note that $\frac{s^2}{S^2}$ is the square of $\frac{s}{S}$, so yes they are very clearly connected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why is the ratio of the perimeter "the same" as the ratio of the area. 1:5, 1:25 | 5^2 is 25.

Comment: "Why is the ratio of the perimeter 'the same' as the ratio of the area"   Suppose that you have the ratio of the perimeter as $1:p$ and you have the ratio of the area as $1:A$.  You have then $A=p^2$.  This is because $A=\frac{s^2}{S^2} = \left(\frac{s}{S}\right)^2=(p)^2$ as I explained in my first comment.

Comment: Thank you! For explaining this for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite general and comes from the dimesionality of area and perimeter.  If you scale any figure up by a factor $k$ the area increases by a factor $k^2$ and the perimeter increases by a factor $k$.  The ratio area/perimeter then increases by a factor $k$ as well.

In three dimensions on scaling a figure by $k$ the volume scales as $k^3$ and the surface area by $k^2$